# Query to fetch row value available in same table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to fetch the row value available in the same table using join query .

example :

```
Id (Primary Key)   Name       Address   Parent Organization ID (Foreign Key) reference (Id)

1                  Sup Org1   Address1  null

2                  Sup Org2   Address2  null

3                  Sup Org3   Address3  null

4                  Sub Org5   Address4  1
```

Output:

```
Name                Address

Sup Org1            Address1  

Sup Org2            Address2

Sup Org3            Address3 

Sub Org5(Sup Org1)  Address4
```

Except the Super organaization value all the sub organization should be appended with
the mapped Super Organziation (ex: Sub Org5(Org1)).

Could any one help me out on this to write query to fetch like above output format

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but this should cover

```
Select 
   t1.Name || Decode(NVL(t2.Name , ''), '', '', '(' || t2.Name || ')'), -- here we convert null to empty string and don't wrap empty string into parenthesis
   Address
From Mytable t1 left join
     Mytable t2 on t1.id = t2.Parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d0e3/9) (which you should supply next time you have a question like this) and here's the SQL:

```
SELECT o2.Name, case when o1.Name is not null then '(' || o1.Name || ')' END, o2.Parent_Organization_ID, 01.Address
FROM Organization o1
RIGHT JOIN Organization o2 on o1.id = o2.Parent_Organization_ID
ORDER BY o2.NAME
```

Answer (score -1):

the procedure you're looking for is called a "self join". sql zoo has some lessons that might help sharpen your skills.

no fiddle provided, but this looks about right to me:

```
select sub.name||coalesce('('||sup.name||')',''),address
from table_name as sub
left join table_name as sup on sub.parent=sup.id
```